# Where is F# Interactive on Mac

Tags: macos, f#, mono, f#-interactive

On Windows, the executables for F# Interactive and the F# Compiler are named `fsi` and `fsc`. On Mac with Mono, they're called `fsharpi` and `fsharpc`. Why is that?

Comment: For whatever reason I could not find them. They're located in `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/fsharp`

Comment: Type `which fsharpc` and `which` will tell you where in your path that the command was found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those names are just the Mono script wrappers for `fsi.exe` and `fsc.exe`.

They are the same CIL-based "exe" wrapped in a `sh` script to execute them via the `mono` runtime. Create some aliases in the shell of choice if you want to.

#### /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpc

```
#!/bin/sh
EXEC="exec "

if test x"$1" = x--debug; then
   DEBUG=--debug
   shift
fi

if test x"$1" = x--gdb; then
   shift
   EXEC="gdb --eval-command=run --args "
fi

if test x"$1" = x--valgrind; then
  shift
  EXEC="valgrind $VALGRIND_OPTIONS"
fi

# Beware this line must match the regular expression " (\/.*)\/fsi\.exe" when fsc.exe is fsi.exe.
# That's because the FSharp MonoDevelop addin looks inside the text of this script to determine the installation
# location of the default FSharp install in order to find the FSharp compiler binaries (see
# fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/Services/CompilerLocationUtils.fs). That's a pretty unfortunate
# way of finding those binaries. And really should be changed.
$EXEC /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/bin/mono $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/fsharp/fsc.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

#### /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpi

```
#!/bin/sh
EXEC="exec "

if test x"$1" = x--debug; then
   DEBUG=--debug
   shift
fi

if test x"$1" = x--gdb; then
   shift
   EXEC="gdb --eval-command=run --args "
fi

if test x"$1" = x--valgrind; then
  shift
  EXEC="valgrind $VALGRIND_OPTIONS"
fi

# Beware this line must match the regular expression " (\/.*)\/fsi\.exe" when fsi.exe is fsi.exe.
# That's because the FSharp MonoDevelop addin looks inside the text of this script to determine the installation
# location of the default FSharp install in order to find the FSharp compiler binaries (see
# fsharpbinding/MonoDevelop.FSharpBinding/Services/CompilerLocationUtils.fs). That's a pretty unfortunate
# way of finding those binaries. And really should be changed.
$EXEC /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/bin/mono $DEBUG $MONO_OPTIONS /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.16.0/lib/mono/fsharp/fsi.exe --exename:$(basename "$0") "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Terminal** window, with `bash` shell:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsharpi /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/fsi
```

Then `fsi` should work. If not, make sure that the directory above is in your PATH: `echo $PATH`